# How to get a color ID by String value?

Tags: android, android-resources

I have a String that has a value of "c104":

```
String color = "c104";
```

and I have a color with the name "c104":

```
<color name="c104">#000000</color>
```

How can I get that color by that String value?

I can't make it like `R.id.color;`

Is there any way to convert that String to an ID?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a [`getIdentifier()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method to retrieve the resource ID for arbitrary resources, including colors:

```
String colorName = "c104";
int colorResId = getResources().getIdentifier(colorName, "color", getPackageName());
```

That would be the same as:

```
int colorResId = R.color.c104;
```